# ASP.NET. Можно ли создать модель и тут же получить ее ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть форма где создаю владельца питомца, и в ней же сразу выбираю самих питомцев.
Выходит таблица Owners, Pets и связь между ними 1:M OwnerToPets.

`Owner`:

```
string Name
List<OwnerToPets> OwnerToPets
```

`Pets`:

```
string Name
```

`OwnerToPets`:

```
int ownerId
int petId
```

То есть получается что при клике на кнопку сохранить - у нас должен создаваться владелец и сразу после этого в связанную таблицу добавляться записи с ID питомца и ID владельца(а вот тут то мы и должны как то получать ID владельца)

Как это можно реализовать?

P.S. Можно получить id банально выбрав самый последний. Но вдруг одновременно сохраняют 3-6 пользователей?

Comment: Открыли транзакцию, наполнили объект владельца, сохранили. Появился id владельца. Наполнили объект питомца, прописали туда id владельца, сохранили. Закрыли транзакцию. А вообще в подобных вопросах принято структуры Owners и Pets приводить. И кстати, писать EF у вас или EF Core. К слову говоря, и вопрос-то этот уже отвечали, Павел Майоров автор ответов, можете поискать если что непонятно.

Comment: Во-первых, третья таблица необязательно; достаточно двух. Во-вторых, вы не указали используемые технологии. В-третьих, как уже сказано в ответе, можно использовать guid в качестве ключа.

Comment: Уточните: ваш вопрос по работе с базой данных? Тогда зачем в заголовке и метках стоит asp.net? Удалите лишнее и добавьте, какую технологию используете для работы с БД (явно EF, но укажите версию)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, т.к. в нём не приведены существенные сведения, про которые частично хоть что-то узнаёшь после ответа. Оказывается, это и не таблица, а Enum.

Comment: @AK это отдельная таблица которую я использую для видов питомцев. Еще у меня мозг кипит, ок? Пытаюсь решить и иногда заглядываю сюда.
Использую EF (не core). Таблица связей между ними мне нужна(чтоб не засорять записями другие таблицы).

Comment: @AK что подразумевается под структурой? Если свойства моделей - то я вкратце выписал основные выше, чтоб не копировать всё.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно модель 1:M хранится в одном классе и список в нем дабы знать основной объект.

```
class Owner {
  // Id и прочие поля
  ....
  public List<Pet> Pets {....};
}


class Pet {
// Id и прочие
.....
}
```

При такой схеме у вы сможете создавать не зная id и сохранять по иерархии.

Другой вариант сделать id GUID и назначать самому.

Comment: Виноват что не уточнил сразу, но в Pet находятся лишь перечисления питомцев, т.е. (Кошка, Собака, Попугай итд.) По факту мы выбираем из готового варианта.
Если мне не изменяет память - То после таких добавлений начнут появляться дубликаты в Pet, но мб я ошибаюсь.

Comment: @AskAlexandria В C# вам не нужно делат таблицу ссылок, так как `List<Pet>` технически это и есть ссылки на объекты. Саму таблицу ссылок нужно будет иметь только в базе. А вообще если вам не суперктитична мегапроизводительность, то ссылки можно держать односторонние. То есть внутри пета список его хозяев не требуется. Тогда найти всех хозяев у кого есть попугай можно будет легко `owners.Where(owner => owner.Pets.Contains(parrot))`.